# Get POST body data in Silex RESTful API

Tags: symfony, silex

I am creating a RESTful API using Silex.  To test I am using Chrome's "Simple REST Client" addon.

In the addon I set the URL to: http://localhost/api-test/web/v1/clients
I set the "method" to: POST
I leave the "headers" blank
I set the "data" to: name=whatever

In my "clients.php" page I have:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->post('/clients', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
  return new Response('Created client with name: ' . $request->request->get('name'), 201);
}
```

In the addon, the output shows: "Status: 201" (correct), a bunch of headers, and "Data: Created client with name: " (it should say "Data: Created client with name: whatever"

What am I doing wrong? I also tried: $request->get('name')

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure to send the Content-Type header with your request (i.e. `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Comment: @xabbuh I am not creating a form, I am creating an API.  Is that still necessary?

Comment: @xabbuh Adding your header does work with the "data" I provided, thank you.  My Ember.js front-end will actually be submitting JSON, so the "data" POSTed will more likely be: { "name": "whatever" }, but when I use this data and the header "Content-Type: application/json" or "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" it does not output the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three steps were needed to resolve:

1) In "Simple Rest Client" set the "Headers" to:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

2) Change the "Data" to:

```
{ "name": "whatever" }
```

3) In Silex add the code to convert input to JSON, as described at http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json') === 0) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
});
```

Then I was able to access the data in my PHP code with:

```
$request->request->get('name')
```

Thank you @xabbuh for your help, which led me towards the answer.

Comment: you should use:
return new JsonResponse(array('1','a'));